# Write an SQL query that lists names of students in decreasing order of total marks received in all subjects

Tags: mysql

Hi i got this  question in one of the interview to be solved.
Write an SQL query that lists names of students in decreasing order of total marks received in all subjects. The output should only contain a single column: StudentName.

O/p : Output should be this

" The output should only contain a single column: StudentName."

```
SELECT name FROM `students` order by marks DESC
```

Comment: What have you tried till now? Show the code.

Comment: @CuriousMind i have added code can you check once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ...

```
SELECT `name` AS StudentName FROM students ORDER BY SUM(marksHere) AS TotalMarks DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there are multiple fields for marks in classes, so you might want to do something like:

```
SELECT `name` AS StudentName
FROM students
GROUP BY StudentName
ORDER BY SUM(Class1Marks+Class2Marks) AS TotalMarks DESC
```

Without knowing more about your exact situation & Table structure, it's hard to say for sure.